# Send SMS reminder the evening before the day a specific task (with a due time) is due

Tags: remember-the-milk

I see there's an option to be sent a reminder a certain period of time before the task is due, but I want a reminder at a specific time of day, the day before the task is due.

Is it possible to get remember the milk to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirements correctly, it appears that Remember The Milk can be configured in this way:
1. Go to Settings
2. Go to Reminders
3. Under the option "*blank* before the task is due, check the box and input "1 day"
4. Under the option "Send daily reminders at" input your desired time.
5. Under the option "I want to be reminded by..." click "Add Details"
6. Select "Mobile"
7. Select your network
8. Input your mobile number

Here is an image of the setup:

[image: screen shot]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "remember the milk" but Google Calendar has amazing notification options that are very easy to use.

To set up notification:

1. go to Google Calendar (google.com/calendar)
2. click the settings wheel button in the top right corner
3. click the "Mobile Setup" tab and set up with your phone information (country, phone number, verification code that is sent to your phone)

To set a default notification setting:

1. click the "Calendars" tab (still in calendar settings)
2. in the row for the calendar you want to make a default setting for, click the Notifications link
3. set your default settings.

I like getting a pop-up if I'm on a Google service a few minutes before, and getting an email and a text message one day before:

[image]

You can also set the notifications individually by clicking on an entry in the calendar.

Comment: Not really a helpful answer. Could do with how it's done in Google Calendar other than saying it can be done.

Comment: Good suggestion, editing now.